# html+javascriptで、前回実行時の変数の値を取得する方法や、変数値を初期化させない方法があれば教えてください

Tags: javascript, html

下記のような処理で、A,B,Cを選択できるラジオボタンを作成し、操作されたらonchangeでjavascriptを呼び出しています。

**HTML**

```html
<div class="buttons" onchange="calc()">
    <input type="radio" name="item" value="A">A
    <input type="radio" name="item" value="B">B
    <input type="radio" name="item" value="C">C
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
switch (document.form1.item.value) {
    case 'A': price=10; break;
    case 'B': price=20; break;
    case 'C': price=30; break;
}
```

ページ作成依頼者より「一度Cが選択された後、AまたはBに戻された時だけメッセージを表示してほしい」と言われ、悩んでいます。

イメージとしては、jsでラジオボタンの位置を保持しておき、その値を参照して処理しようと思っていますが、うまくいきません。

jsのこの処理の後に**temp_price**に値を保存し、この処理の前でその値を参照して処理しようと

```
   if ( temp_price == 30 ){ /*ここに前回Cが選択されていた時の処理を記述*/ }
　 switch (document.form1.item.value) {
        case 'A': price=10; break;
        case 'B': price=20; break;
        case 'C': price=30; break;
    }
　　temp_price = price;
```

こんな感じにすれば実現できるかと思ったのですがうまくいきません。
デベロッパーツールで確認すると、「if～」の行の時点で**temp_price**が常にundefinedになってしまいます。（初回実行時にundefinedなのは想定していましたが、２回目以降は10,20,30のいずれかが入ってくるつもりでコーディングしました）

JavaScriptで、「前回実行時の変数の値を取得する方法」あるいは「複数回呼び出されても、変数を初期化させない方法」などありましたら、ご教示お願いいたします。

Comment: 「前回ページ訪問時の状態」ではなく、「前回関数実行時の状態」を保存できればよいのですね? temp_priceはどのように宣言していますか?  できれば、コードの部分引用ではなく実行可能な完全なコードを示していただくと解決策を出しやすいです。

Comment: コードを見てると、「form1」が無さそうなのですが実際はhtml内にあるのでしょうか？

Comment: コード全てを掲載するとあまりに長くなってしまうので抜粋したつもりでしたが、中途半端な質問になってしまったようで、申し訳ありません。
回答ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSのグローバル変数を利用すれば行けそうです。

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var objValue;
objValue="";
function ValueChange(obj)
{
    if(objValue=="C"){
        alert("sssssssss");
    }

    objValue= obj.value;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1">

<div class="buttons" onchange="calc()">
    <input type="radio" name="item" onchange="ValueChange(this);" value="A">A
    <input type="radio" name="item" onchange="ValueChange(this);" value="B">B
    <input type="radio" id="CCC" name="item" onchange="ValueChange(this);" value="C">C
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！
まさにこれが私が実現したかった事で、こちらのソースを参考に、実装する事ができました！